# Checking if a Ruby program was executed or imported via require

Tags: ruby, command-line

How do you check if a Ruby file was imported via "require" or "load" and not simply executed from the command line?

For example:

Contents of foo.rb:

```
puts "Hello"
```

Contents of bar.rb

```
require 'foo'
```

Output:

```
$ ./foo.rb
Hello
$ ./bar.rb
Hello
```

Basically, I'd like calling bar.rb to not execute the puts call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change foo.rb to read:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  puts "Hello"
end
```

That checks `__FILE__` - the name of the current ruby file - against `$0` - the name of the script which is running.

Answer (score 5):

```
if __FILE__ != $0       #if the file is not the main script which is running
  quit                  #then quit
end
```

Put this on top of all code in foo.rb

Answer (score 1):

For better readability you can also use  `$PROGRAM_NAME`

```
  if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
      puts "Executed via CLI #{__FILE__}"
    else
      puts 'Referred'
    end
```

More info: [What does __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME mean in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101151/what-does-file-program-name-mean-in-ruby)