# What does __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, special-variables

I have stumbled across this sintax while reviewing a code in Ruby. The code is:

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  #some code...
end
```

I suppose `__FILE__` is a variable that gets me the name of the file I am in?
But what does `$PROGRAM_NAME` simbolize then? Also, why is this if statement necessary, since the program works with or without it?

Comment: The point of the question isn't just the meaning of `__FILE__`, but the point of the comparison, so it's a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687680/what-does-if-file-0-mean-in-ruby (`$PROGRAM_NAME` and `$0` being the same thing).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`__FILE__` always returns the path of the source file. It's not a variable so you can't assign value to it. Whether it returns a relative path or an absolute one depends on how you run the script.

`$PROGRAM_NAME` or `$0` by default returns the command that boots the program (minus the path of ruby interpreter). For example, you have a script file `test.rb` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts __FILE__
puts $PROGRAM_NAME
```

If you run this script with `ruby test.rb`, it prints

```
test.rb
test.rb
```

If you run the script with `ruby /path/to/test.rb`, it prints

```
/path/to/test.rb
/path/to/test.rb
```

If you give the script an execution permission and run it with `./test.rb`, it prints

```
./test.rb
./test.rb
```

Unlike `__FILE__`, `$PROGRAM_NAME` and `$0` are real global variables, and you can change their values. `$PROGRAM_NAME` and `$0` are aliases to each other, so you change the value of either one, the value of the other will change accordingly. For example, you have a `test2.rb` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$0 = 'Hello, world!'
puts $0
puts $PROGRAM_NAME
```

it prints

```
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a great explanation!

Comment: `$PROGRAM_NAME` is very hard to find in documentation (`$0` in contrast, is easy). In terms of official-ish docs, I could only find `$PROGRAM_NAME` mentioned in the Pragmatic Programmer's book, and only under the `English` module (even though you don't actually need to require English).

Answer (score 1):

`__FILE__` is the current source file name.

It seems to ruby code wants to make sure that the current file corresponds to the program that needs to executed.

`$` before a variable, means its a global variable.

Check here to know more - http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#18